# "between X and Y" vs. "between X to Y"

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

> It is estimated that there were between twenty-five **to** forty African American deaths.
>
> (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlanta_Race_Riot)

Could the wikipedia quote above be considered "standard" English in reference to the "to" usage? Or, is this "to" usage a tollerated mistake?

Comment: I'd revise it to "**between 25 and 40**" or "**from 25 to 40**". It's Wikipedia, the epitome of egalitarian democracy (i.e., homage to the tyranny of the lowest common denominator because it recognizes no authorities weightier than pluralities and majorities).

Comment: @BillFranke, you should add an answer with what you said, because you are right, and I don't want to steal the rep from you by posting it as an answer.

Comment: Wikipedia is the Chuck Norris of English. If it says something, IT IS RIGHT!!!!!!

Comment: @KenB: It's okay if you want to post that as an answer. I won't consider it "stolen rep". If I were really anxious about rep, I'd post more answers and fewer comments. Please notice that my comment is 30% answer & 70% editorial. :-)

Comment: Fixed that on Wikipedia. On a related note, you can say "25 to 40" without any "from" (or "between" for that matter) too. "between" feels more "exclusive" (not 25, not 40, just between), "from" (and bare "to") feel more inclusive (25 and 40 included in the possible number) but this distinction is not written in stone.

Answer (score 2):

The correct phrase is "between twenty-five and forty African American deaths" which is what is said in similar phrases:

- a woman aged between 18 and 30
- between 25 and 40 percent off children's clothes

In all these cases, the phrase gives the minimum and the maximum value: The number of deaths is higher than twenty-five, and lower than forty; the woman age is higher than 18, but lower than 30. (In both the cases, the extremes are usually included.)

Comment: Yes. *Between* requires two values or objects, but *25 to 40* is a single range. You may say there were ***from** 25 **to** 40*.

Comment: Right, but you don't say "between 25 to 40."

Comment: Exactly. *Between 25 **and** 40*.